# enable_shared_from_this and objects on stack

Tags: c++, boost, smart-pointers

Is there a way to prevent shared_from_this() call for a stack-allocated object ?

The enable_shared_from_this<> in the base classes list is a strong indicator for class user, but is there a way to enforce the correct usage ?

Example code:

```
class C : public enable_shared_from_this<C>
{
public:
  shared_ptr<C> method() { return shared_from_this(); }
};

void func()
{
  C c;
  shared_ptr<C> ptr = c.method(); // exception coming from shared_from_this()
}
```

Comment: What are you asking exactly? Do you want to know if there's a way to prevent calling `shared_from_this()` on stack-allocated objects?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

So to protect against this problem you can make your constructors private and only provide creation functions that return shared_ptr - this way the object can't be allocated on the stack, like this:

```
class C : public enable_shared_from_this<C>
{
public:
  static shared_ptr<C> create() { return shared_ptr<C>(new C() ); }
  shared_ptr<C> method() { shared_from_this(); }

private:
  C() {...}

  // Make operator= and C(const C&) private unimplemented
  // so the used cant do bad things like C c( * c_ptr );
  C& operator=( const C & );
  C( const C & );
};


void func()
{
  C c; // This doesn't compile
  shared_ptr<C> ptr = c.method(); // So you can never get this
}

void altfunc()
{
  shared_ptr<C> c_ptr = C::create();
  C & c_ref = *c;
  shared_ptr<C>  ptr = c_ref.method(); // OK
}
```

If you find yourself wishing for an `operator=` you can provide a clone function using a private implemented copy constructor, something like this

```
// This goes in class C
shared_ptr<C> C::clone() const
{
  return shared_ptr<C>( new C(*this) );
}

// This is how you can use it
shared_ptr<C> c2 = c1->clone();
```

Comment: I'm aware that you can probably still allocate these on the stack if you're willing to jump through some hoops to be intentionally evil.. but IMHO this protects from most innocent mistakes.

Comment: So we will initially design heap-only classes... Is this approach are widely used ?

Comment: Why do you need to disable the assignment operator?  It is normally fine to assign to/from objects held in shared_ptr.  It would be handled the same as any other assignment between two *existing* objects -- reference counts would not be affected.  The two *different* objects would just have the same contents after the assignment.

Comment: @nobar - Technically you're correct. Though I'd usually be using something like this with (i) polymorphic behavior - in which case operator= is bad, or (ii) expensive deep copies - in which case operator= is bad. There are probably other use cases though where operator= is useful.

Answer (score 2):

I found the solution.

In Dune library they use stack-compatible `enable_shared_from_this` class template adaptation.

Check the original source code [here](https://gitlab.dune-project.org/lars.lubkoll/dune-common/blob/fbb10d91e59b45c71e48d8f433526748bb031db7/dune/functions/common/shared_from_this.hh) or check my example with the quick copy&paste & cleanup of code:

```cpp
#include <cstdio>
#include <cassert>
#include <memory>
#include <iostream>

template<class T>
struct null_deleter
{
    void operator() (T*) const {}
};
template<typename T>
inline std::shared_ptr<T> stackobject_to_shared_ptr(T & t)
{
    return std::shared_ptr<T>(&t, null_deleter<T>());
}

template<typename T, typename T2>
inline std::shared_ptr<T2> stackobject_to_shared_ptr(T & t)
{
    return std::shared_ptr<T2>(dynamic_cast<T2*>(&t), null_deleter<T2>());
}

template<typename T>
class stack_compatible_enable_shared_from_this
: public std::enable_shared_from_this<T>
{
public:
    std::shared_ptr<T> shared_from_this()
    {
        try
        {
            return std::enable_shared_from_this<T>::shared_from_this();
        }
        catch (std::bad_weak_ptr&)
        {
            _local_ptr = stackobject_to_shared_ptr(*static_cast<T*>(this));
            return _local_ptr;
        }
    }
    
    std::shared_ptr<const T> shared_from_this() const
    {
        try
        {
            return std::enable_shared_from_this<T>::shared_from_this();
        }
        catch (std::bad_weak_ptr&)
        {
            _local_ptr = stackobject_to_shared_ptr(*const_cast<T*>(static_cast<const T*>(this)));
            return _local_ptr;
        }
    }
    
private:
    
    mutable std::shared_ptr<T> _local_ptr;
};

struct MyObj : public stack_compatible_enable_shared_from_this<MyObj>{};

int main (int argc, char **argv) {
    //std::shared_ptr<MyObj> so = std::make_shared<MyObj>(6);
    MyObj o{};
    auto * so = &o;
    {
        auto l = std::weak_ptr<MyObj>(so->shared_from_this());
        auto shared = l.lock();
        if (shared) { } //use it
    }
}
```

Comment: This is very dangerous.  Great care should be taken to avoid the situation where the stack object goes out of scope while shared pointers pseudo-owning it are still floating around.  I would not recommend this approach unless you are sure what you're doing.

Comment: @AlexanderShukaev I agree. Although the ref-counting mechanism will work correctly, the problem with stack memory is it will be overwritten by another stack frame allocations. So it looks like it doesn't make sense to do this. The only reason if you really need the shared_ptr semantics (say your interface only supports shared_ptr<Type> calls) and you're absolutely sure that it won't leave the nested call stack i.e the solid object on stack will be deallocated only after all shared_ptrs...